# Can SQL server verify client with SSL cert, that tries to connect to it?

Tags: postgresql, ssl

Pretty sure that it's stupid question, but still would be very happy to get answer or some explanation or point to the documentation.

Right now I'm configuring [SSL connection to PostgreSQL server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html) with certificates. And as I'm unfortunately not so good in connection and security stuff, I've realised that was completely sure that server should check who is connecting to it `server [check] <-- client`, but in reality - a client checks whether it connects to the right server `server <-- [check] client`.

Why it's so? Why not vice versa, why not in both directions?

Thank you for any reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the client library documentation, no wonder it doesn't say anything about the server. The server can indeed be configured for [certificate authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-cert.html).

At a minimum, that requires turning `ssl = on` in the configuration and supplying a private key `server.key`
and a public key `server.crt`.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's much more clear. The next goal to reach data from `/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` inside google cloud :). But that's a different story.